# Quarkus OIDC- Hybrid application type. How to specify type at endpoint level

Tags: java, quarkus-oidc

I am working on setting up OIDC on my app, which has both regular REST endpoints, and UI ones. I want to setup the OIDC auth flow for the UI endpoints, and a simpler 401 situation for the other REST endpoints.

I noticed that `quarkus.oidc.application-type` has the `hybrid` value, but having a hard time determining how to use this correctly, or what annotations would be appropriate in the different cases. Is my use case what `hybrid` is made for?

I noticed there is `@Authenticated`, `@OAuthFlow(s)`, `@OAuthScope`, but it isn't clear how these fit together.